# Firebase Realtime DB: Remove node as part of atomic update

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to perform an update in a Firebase Realtime database that adds a key to a table and deletes a key from a table:

```
firebase.database().ref('/').update({
  [`/users/${a}/womp`]: true,
  [`/users/${b}`]: 'delete_me',
})
```

Is there a way to include a `remove()` operation as part of an atomic update? Any pointers others can offer would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the value `null`, it deletes stuff:

```
firebase.database().ref('/').update({
  [`/users/${a}/womp`]: true,
  [`/users/${b}`]: null,
})
```

Doing this will delete everything at `/users/${b}`.

Comment: haha, I guess it does (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write). Does setting the value to `null` remove the key?

Comment: when you set any node to `null`, it gets deleted. What do you mean "the key"?

Comment: but I can't include a delete call in an atomic update, can I? By "the key" I just meant the thing that maps to a value. (I think of the Firebase Realtime DB as a giant JS object)

Comment: Yes, in that sense, the "key" is deleted in RTDB.

Comment: Thanks. hf deleting stuff